# How to solve cache slamming / stampeding case with Varnish?

Tags: caching, varnish

I'm considering to use Varnish as a caching solution for our infrastructure and I would like to ask if there a mechanism inside Varnish, which solves [cache slamming / stampeding problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_stampede)?

Answer (score 2):

Since Varnish 4.0, You can serve stale while revalidate using the grace time (https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/grace-varnish-4-stale-while-revalidate-semantics-varnish ).

Varnish will asynchronously fetch the response from the backend and serve the stale cached content if it is in its grace period.

Comment: Will it really protect from cache slam? How many such async refresh requests will hit the backend if, say, 10 users are requesting the same resource, which cache has just expired?

Comment: It is to be checked by looking at the source code (or by asking the mailing list) but I think that the response is only one request. Prior to varnish 4, there was also only one request. the other requests were stucked waiting for the first one to refresh the cache.

Comment: I agree with @BenjaminBaumann, to me only one request will go to the backend when one is being generated.

Comment: The doc here seems to state that bg fetch are done in parallel if object is expired. https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/a96e465904beb9e193d55d55be3247d4a3255b9d/doc/graphviz/cache_req_fsm.svg I keep looking for the information within the source code.

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann Thanks. Ping me, please, if you find something.